# MySQL: двухтабличный запрос c сортировкой по количеству позиций

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Есть 2 таблицы - `shop_users` и `shop_cart`, необходимо извлечь всех пользователей с не пустой корзиной и отсортировать по количеству товаров в ней. Результат должен выдать обязательно `shop_users.*`

```
shop_users (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  ...
)

shop_cart (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select u.*, count(1) cnt
  from shop_users u
  join shop_cart  c on c.user_id=u.id
 group by u.id
 order by cnt
```

В вашем вопросе оказались разночтения. Мне показалось, что количество товаров в корзине - это количество записей в таблице `shop_cart`, запрос написан исходя из этого. Если же под количеством товаров понимается сумма поля `count` из этой таблицы то в запросе надо заменить `count(1)` на `sum(c.count)`.

Если в MySQL включена опция only_full_group_by то в "group by" придется перечислить все поля из shop_users.

А вообще вы бы зашли на какой нибудь сайт типа [sql-ex.ru](http://www.sql-ex.ru/) и поучили SQL, оно пригодится. Запрос то тут на уровне первых уроков ...

Comment: емнип join обычно сильно затратней чем where

Comment: @rjhdby откуда такие данные ? во всех источниках "просто по SQL" пишут обратное. В документации на MySQL черным по белому написано, что оператор запятая полностью синтаксически эквивалентно join и inner join. И оно реально дает одинаковый план выполнения

Comment: @rjhdby Только что проверил на большой таблице план выполнения для join и where. Они абсолютно одинаковые. пожалуйста подкрепляйте свои слова реальными примерами

Comment: значит память подводит :) Вообще предубеждение против join взялось когда пришлось искать узкие места в одном проекте, где замена двух-страничного запроса с join'ами на гораздо более короткий(но идентичный!) запрос с простыми условиями дало выигрыш в производительности на пару порядков.

Comment: @rjhdby Учитывая, что я вообще работал всегда с Oracle в котором до 9й версии вообще слова join не существовало я join никогда не использую. Но на SO я стараюсь писать по стандартам SQL, что бы ответ мог работать на произвольных RDBMS (ну кроме старых ораклов :)).

Answer (score 0):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  u.*,
  SUM(c.count) AS total
FROM
  shop_cart AS c
LEFT JOIN
  shop_users AS u
ON
  c.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY
  c.user_id
ORDER BY
  total DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(t2.count) AS cnt, t1.* 
FROM shop_users t1, shop_cart t2
WHERE t1.id=t2.user_id
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING sum(t2.count)>0
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: Цитирую автора вопроса "_Результат должен выдать обязательно shop_users.*_". под этим по моему подразумевается, что в результате должны быть все данные из таблицы пользователей. Вы другого мнения ?

Comment: @Mike мне кажется, что вы неверно интерпретировали вопрос. Там четко указано, что "всех пользователей с не пустой корзиной". а shop_users.* - это все ПОЛЯ данного пользователя. Кстати хочу заметить, что в вашем варианте не учитывается количество заказанных товаров(поле count) и не учитывается, что count может быть равен 0

Comment: Там count _не может_ быть равен нулю. потому как используется обычных join, а не left join. И обычный join не выдаст запись если хотя бы в одной из соединяемых таблиц не окажется подходящей записи

Comment: @Mike я про поле `count` в таблице `shop_cart`. Товар может быть один, но в 10 экземплярах, тогда ваш запрос вернет 1, а мой 10. Так же это поле, гипотетически, может быть равно 0. Но согласен - это скорее двусмысленность вопроса, что автор считает количеством товара в корзине